# Intergration of Docker with OpenStack via Docker Heat Plugin

Tags: networking, docker, openstack, openstack-heat

I'm trying to integrate Docker with OpenStack (icehouse) via the Docker-Heat Pluigin and I'm facing a problem.

OpenStack is configured according to the tutorial by OpenStack for Ubuntu. I'm using a controller node and a compute node (just the 2 nodes) with the legacy nova-networking.

**Things to keep in mind**:

Controller Node: 1 network interface - management interface

Compute Node : 2 network interfaces - management interface and the external interface (vm instance have ips of the same subnet of that external interface)

With OpenStack everything works perfect except (which might be the problem I'm facing for dockers)

1- You can't reach (ping) the deployed vm instances from the controller node [makes sense, i think no problem in that one]

2- You can't reach (ping) the deployed vm instances from the compute node (ping: operation not permitted) [might be the issue] - but you can ping from a vm instance to the compute node

3- The virtual machines themselves don't see each others [but i think doesn't have relation to the issue im facing]

For Dockers, the plug-in is installed. I assume perfect since the syntax for Dockers DockerInc::Docker ... is accepted but when I try to run the example posted in the Docker blog - making the adjustments required - the compute instance is created but the docker container is not. Im having this error:

**When i try it as a user with admin role**
MissingSchema: Invalid URL u'192.168.122.26/v1.9/containers/None/json': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http:/ /192.168.122.26/v1.9/containers/None/json

**When i try it as a user with just a *member* role**
MissingSchema: Invalid URL u'192.168.122.26/v1.9/containers/create': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http:/ /192.168.122.26/v1.9/containers/create

Notes:
192.168.122.26 is the ip of the created vm instance.
I've tried not only with cirros but also coreos and ubunto-precise (same error)
Docker itsself is installed on both Controller and Compute.
Docker plugin and its requirements are only installed on the controller node

Finally, both the controller and the compute nodes run as virtual machines themselves

I would be really glad if you had an idea. Thanks for your time,

Kindest Regards,
M. El Sioufy

Comment: Changed in the template to make append http:// to the return ip address and now i have a connection timeout error

Timeout: (<urllib3.connectionpool.HTTPConnectionPool object at 0x7f30ca6cbf10>, 'Connection to 192.168.122.26 timed out. (connect timeout=60)')

Comment: Note that the example on the docker blog is grossly inaccurate.  The HTTPConnection problem is probably caused by the fact that you have Heat trying to create Docker containers before Docker is actually installed and running.  You can solve this using Heat wait conditions.  [Here](https://github.com/larsks/heat-docker-example/blob/master/docker-server.yml) is a working example.

Comment: This is mostly for folks finding their way here via Google: I've turned that example into a blog post that goes into Heat and Docker in a little more detail: http://blog.oddbit.com/2014/08/30/docker-plugin-for-openstack-he/

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you haven't allowed communication to the VMs from the outside world (which the controller and/or the compute node will be from the VM's point of view).  By default, communications *from* VMs to the outside world are allowed, but not inbound *to* the VMs.  Try adding an "allow all TCP" rule to the default security group of the tenant that the VMs live in.  This may fix your HTTP timeout.

Comment: THanks John, unfortunately this is not the solution still. I have been in contact with Docker members and advised to resolve the openstack networking issues first ... I solved quite some of them but remaining only one (Ping from controller to vms). I posed another question can you please take a look at it. Thanks for your help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23677347/openstack-networking-issue-cant-ping-from-controller-node-to-virtual-machine-i